# Disable the Captive portal detection in android

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

```
WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();
                        String ssid = result.SSID;
                        wc.SSID ="\""+ AccessPointName+"\"";
                        wc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;

                        wc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);


                        int res = wifiManager.addNetwork(wc);
                        boolean x= wifiManager.enableNetwork(res, true);
                        wifiManager.reconnect();
```

This ssid uses captive portal, is there any configuration to stop android from checking captive portal.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Hi, did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the following commands in terminal as root:

settings put global captive_portal_server 127.0.0.1 && settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0